# Laravel - how to prevent redirection after login and middleware?

Tags: laravel

I would like to prevent laravel from redirecting after login, when it fails. I don't manage. It always redirects to /myspace, even if it fails.

I tried adding this in login page but then it redirects to the same page with "302 Found".
The problem is that I am using VueJS to logg in, in a modal. So I want it not to redirect anywhere so that I can notify the user that his credentials are wrong.

[EDIT] it works!

vuelogin(){

```
        axios.post("/login", {_token:this.csrf, email:this.email, password:this.password, headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }},).then(
            response => {
                window.location='/myspace';
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            this.error = error.response;
        });;
    },





protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ( $user->id!=null ) {
            return redirect()->route('myspace');
        }
        return "NOPE";
    }
```

Here is LoginController:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $redirectTo = '/myspace';
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}

public function password()
{
    return 'password';
}
```

I have a middleware associated with this login:

```
class LoginNewPassword
{
    function newPwdExists($login){
        //bla bla bla
    }

    public function remembermembretoken(){
        //blablabla
        return true;
    }


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($this->newPwdExists($request->email)==0)
        {
            return redirect('/password/reset')->with('email',$request->email);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        $loggedin = $this->remembermembretoken();
        if($loggedin) return redirect('/myspace');
        return $response; **//if I remove this, I get the error "Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object"**
    }
}
```

Here is Login.vue

```
<template>
    <form method="POST" id="formlogin" action="/vuelogin" style="margin: 1em;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
        <div class=" login-card itra-green-bgr text-center" v-if="isloggedin==false" style="padding-top:1em;">
            <!-- <label style="color: white; font-family:Montserrat-ExtraBold;" for="rememberme">{{ $t('login.login') }}</label> -->
            <hr/>
            <input id="email" type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" style="margin-bottom: 1em;" required autofocus>

            <input id="password" type="password" v-model="password" :placeholder="$t('login.password')" class="form-control" name="password">
            <div class="error" v-if="error!=''">{{$t('login.badcredentials')}}</div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">

                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                        {{ $t('login.rememberme') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="">
                    <button style="margin: 1em;" type="submit" class="btn-itra-black">
                        {{ $t('login.login') }}
                    </button>


                    <div style="margin: 1em;">
                        <a style="color:black" href="/password/reset">
                            {{ $t('login.forgotpwd') }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div><a class="btn-itra-white" href="/register">{{ $t('login.noAccount') }}</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        nom: "login",
        data () {
            return {
                APP_URL: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
                isloggedin: false,
                loggedin: '',
                email: '',
                password:'',
                rememberme:false,
                currentUser: null,
                csrf: "",
                error:''
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
          this.csrf = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        },
        methods:{
            register(){
                window.location.href = this.APP_URL +'/register/';
            },
            logout(){
              axios.post("/logout");
            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send a header `Content-Type: application/json` from your javascript login request, and Laravel will make sure it returns the validation errors as a JSON array immediately, instead of redirecting with an errorbag.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to send it through axios I guess? I updated my answer with vuelogin, where I am sending the form directly. Otherwise I didn't manage to send the csrf token correctly...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I update my question with the working solution